# KD-tree in a MongoDB DB collection

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, indexing, kdtree

I am trying to solve the k nearest neighbor problem on a set of objects in 3-space.  These objects live in a MongoDB collection with all the joy and sorrow that comes with document based storage.  Given one object I would like to find the k nearest neighbors in the fewest queries as possible.  the collection sized is expected to be about 10^5 and k is between 10 and 50.  I would really prefer not to have to store the entire tree in memory.

How could one store a KD-Tree in a MongoDB collection?

Comment: P.S. if you think I can somehow use MongoDB 2d indexes to solve my 3d problem please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5436119/163177 instead.

Comment: Full N-D indexing is 'planned' for MongoDB (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-691, and the GIST mention at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-91). They know about it at least. Beyond that I have nothing but the lame answer to use 2D as a starting point (scale your values if need be!) and, search through the last dimension. Otherwise, perhaps use PostGRE, which I understand does full N-D indexing.