# Find most recent & closest posts, limit 20

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mongodb

I saw a question here recently and bookmark it for further thought. This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003943/find-most-recent-closest-posts-limit-20). What I can't determine myself is if this question is really interesting or nothing special?

Why this is, its because it looked to me that it had a real simple answer sort by lowest distance*time product, or am I missing something obvious?

I can explain the reason why it looked simple to me:

1. Distance is always somewhat constant no matter when or where the query is ran, meaning that if: My home is at point A and there is a post at point B and another post at point C, no matter when I ran the query I will always get the constant values say 5km & 7km.
2. The time offset since the post looks like it's **also** somewhat constant in a sense that it grows equally for all posts. Meaning that if post B is from 2004 and post C is from 2009, now they will be 7 years and 2 years ago respectively. So next year it will be 8 and 3 years ago and so on.
3. Adding a weight value(s) to 'tweak' the distance & time is not any helpful (not needed) since (taking the values from the two post above) 5*7*alpha will always be more then 2*7*aplha hence no matter when we ran the query post C (2*7*aplha) will always be the 'closest most recent'
4. Also adding a weight constant to 'tweak' the results seems like it's no longer going to product the most closest and recent but will favor either or in which case I may as well sort by most recent and then by most closest or vise versa. But this is no longer the closest more recent but either the closest then more recent or more recent then closest so both those questions are trivial I believe. So this is why I think tweaking is not a good idea no matter what units are chosen to represent the time offset and distance.
   Addition doesn't work as well as multiplication I think but distance*time seems to be sufficient to always get the correct result.

So this is what I was thinking but then I thought, no that can't be that simple. So what am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine the desired sorting expression would be to let some human beings sort some items manually and deduce the expressions from their answers. It may well be that different persons would give different answers, so that one single expression can't accommodate everyone.

There are other useful polynomial expressions such as `t*d + A*t + B*d`, where `t` and `d` are time and distance. Maybe more precise results can be achieved if we introduce one more polynomial degree, so that expression becomes `t*d + A*t*t + B*d*d + C*t + D*d`. Only from answers of real humans can you devise this formula.